# how to restrict sftp only users to specific folder within the chroot directory

Tags: linux, ssh, openssh, sftp

I know there is different versions of this question. but I am trying to give each user a folder within chroot directory and he/she should not be able to navigate outside the assigned folder.

What I have is a Red Hat 7.1 Linux box in the cloud. What I need is:

- create a group exchangefiles
- restrict group to SFTP
- I have more than one user Legacy1, Legacy2, Legacy3

  - Create user/password for each user
  - Create folders under /exchangefolder for each user
  - restrict users to their assigned folders (no navigation outside their folders). e.g.

    - Legacy1 user can only SFTP to /exchangefolder/Legacy1
    - Legacy2 user can only SFTP to /exchangefolder/Legacy2

After this all I need to do whenever I have a new user is to add it to this group and no other group and give it access to a folder under /exchangefolder

I used instructions mentioned in "https://passingcuriosity.com/2014/openssh-restrict-to-sftp-chroot/" then modified "/etc/ssh/sshd_config" by adding

```
Match Group exchangefiles
# Force the connection to use the built-in SFTP support.
ForceCommand internal-sftp 
# Chroot the connection into the specified directory.
#ChrootDirectory /home/exchangefiles/%u
#ChrootDirectory /home/exchangefiles
*ChrootDirectory %h*
# Disable network tunneling
PermitTunnel no
# Disable authentication agent forwarding.
AllowAgentForwarding no
# Disable TCP connection forwarding.
AllowTcpForwarding no
# Disable X11 remote desktop forwarding.
X11Forwarding no
```

created

```
/home/exchangefiles
$ ls -ltr
total 16
drwxrwxr-x 2 root exchangefiles 4096 Jul 11 11:12 files
drwxrwxr-x 2 root exchangefiles 4096 Jul 11 15:31 sftptest2
drwxrwxr-x 3 root exchangefiles 4096 Jul 11 16:16 sftptest1
drwxrwxr-x 3 root exchangefiles 4096 Jul 11 18:32 sftptest3
```

and the folder structure below it.

I created the user as per the link above. but then I tried to set for each user home directory in the jail structure. e.g. USER sftptest1 will have a home directory

```
/home/exchangefiles/sftptest1
```

the problem is that I can not SFTP unless I change

```
ChrootDirectory %h
```

to

```
ChrootDirectory /home/exchangefiles
```

which defeats my purpose of creating separate folder for each user (sort of jail within jail)

is this doable? what is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

From your description it sounds to me as if you want a separate chroot directory for each user: `ChrootDirectory /home/exchangefiles/%u`.